# $f(x)=(d(x;E))^2$ is differentiable almost everywhere on $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

$E\subset \mathbb R$.

Define $f(x)=(d(x;E))^2$ where $d$ is the least Euclidean distance.

Prove that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere on $\mathbb R$.

---

I had some failed (?) attempts to find a counterexample such as Cantor set.

Here is another attempts to prove the argument:

Find a new set $G=\{g:\exists e_1,e_2 $ s.t $d(b;E)=d(b,e_1)=d(b,e_2) \}$

Let $\mathbb R=A_1 + A_2$, where $\forall a_1\in A_1 \ \forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists a\in E$ s.t. $|a-a_1|<\epsilon$.

Then $f'(a_1)=0$.

On the other hand,
$\forall a_2\in A_2$, $\exists \epsilon $ s.t.$\nexists a\in E$ s.t. $a\in B(a_2,\epsilon)$.

Thus $g\in A_2$ are discrete points.

QED?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, one may assume that $E$ is closed since $d(x, E) = d(x, \overline E)$.

Then we split $\mathbb R$ into two regions: (1) $\mathbb R\setminus E$, (2) $E$.

(1) Note that $\mathbb R \setminus E = \cup_i (a_i, b_i)$. For each fixed $i$, the function $f$ is differentiable everywhere on $(a_i, b_i)$ except the midpoint (If $a_i = -\infty$ or $b_i = \infty$, $f$ is differentiable everywhere in the interval). Thus $f$ is almost everywhere differentiable in $\mathbb R \setminus E$.

(2) Let $x_0\in E$. Note that $d(x, E) \le d(x, x_0) = |x-x_0|$. So 
$$ |f(x)-f(x_0)|=|d^2(x, E)| \le |x-x_0|^2.$$
Thus $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ with derivative $=0$.

Hence we've shown that $f$ is differentiable away from a countable discrete set.

**Remark**: Indeed, the [Rademacher theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem) says that any Lipschitz function is differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: I guess it is possible that $\mathbb R\setminus E$ cannot be represented by the union of open sets? For example $\mathbb R\setminus E$ is Cantor set

Comment: $\mathbb{R}\setminus E$ is open, since we assumed WLOG that $E$ is closed.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri That WLOG is so smart!!!

Comment: Indeed it is! The answer is John's though, so kudos to him.

Comment: Great! In my specific case, I think my $f$ is also convex almost everywhere, with the similar proof?

Comment: @HighGPA What is being "convex almost everywhere"?

Comment: @Did Is there a definition that, if a function's double derivative is greater or equal to zero almost everywhere, then we call this function locally convex almost everywhere?

Comment: @HighGPA Oh, so you mentioned "almost everywhere convexity" but have no idea about a definition of the term?

Comment: @Did I had not learned the term "almost everywhere convex" before. Just done some googling. Thanks in advance if you could help